# Angular 5 chunk upload to Web API

Tags: file-upload, angular5

I'm looking for a third-party library that allows **chunked** upload.

I've implemented the upload mechanism towards a Web API without using libraries.

I've done the same thing using **ng2-file-upload**.

They works very well but a big file is sent entirely with only an http call.
I need a chunked upload.

I've found **PrimeNG** but i don't see an option for chunked upload.
Same thing for **ngx-uploader**.

The only library that seems to allow a chunked upload is this one:
https://github.com/kukhariev/ngx-uploadx but the documentation is very poor and i cannot make it works.

Thank you

Comment: Please refer this link https://deliciousbrains.com/using-javascript-file-api-to-avoid-file-upload-limits/

Comment: But in that way i can't use the HttpClient module..